# Rig a monitor for a variable to run a function whenever it changes?

Tags: python

So, I have two objects that represent a user's settings and a user's data. What I'd like to do is have some kind of monitor going that will save the settings/data whenever I change them in my code. I could surely just include a function call after every change, but just as an interesting concept, I was wondering if such an idea was possible.

The first solution that comes to mind is spinning off a thread that will make a copy of the objects and then loop a timer, each time checking if the objects differ from the copy.

Would such a plan be feasible? Is there a better way? The data object could theoretically be kind of large because it stores some cached images and lots of text; would I be causing noticeable performance issues by doing this?

Comment: Are these objects custom-made by you?  If so, just implement the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: This is easily handled by decorators.  It is kind of the "function" option you mentioned but the syntatic sugar makes it nice.  Look up getter and setter decorators in python.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Python to monitor changes to a simple variable.  However, you can do exactly what you want to member variables in a class instance.

Look up "property descriptors".

Here's a nice explanation: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb